# Existential types in Python?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a generic class (say `Automata[S]`) and I'd like another non-generic class (say `Test`) to have `Automata[S]` as a field for some `S` (i.e. I'd like to have `∃S. Automata[S]` as a field).

My first attempt is to use unsubscripted `Automata` type to annotate the field as follows. But the application of `delta` and `is_finale` is not type-safe since type parameter `S` become `Any`.

```py
import abc
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


S = TypeVar('S')


class Automata(Generic[S], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def initial_state(self) -> S:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def delta(self, state: S, x: int) -> S:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_final(self, state: S) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Counter(Automata[int]):
    def initial_state(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def delta(self, state: int, x: int) -> int:
        return state + x

    def is_final(self, state: int) -> bool:
        return state >= 10


class Test:
    automata: Automata

    def __init__(self, automata: Automata[S]):
        self.automata = automata

    def test(self) -> bool:
        s0 = self.automata.initial_state()
        # reveal_type(self.automata) #=> Automata[Any]
        # reveal_type(s0) #=> Any
        s1 = self.automata.delta(s0, 1)
        s2 = self.automata.delta(s1, 2)
        s3 = self.automata.delta(s2, 3)
        return self.automata.is_final(s3)


test = Test(Counter())
test.test()
```

My another attempt is to use the isomorphism `∃X. F(X) ≅ ∀R. (∀X. F(X) → R) → R` as follows. It looks like type-safe as revealed type is not `Any`, but subclassing `Cont` for writing continuation each time is tedious and a bit complex.

```py
import abc
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


S = TypeVar('S')
R = TypeVar('R')


class Automata(Generic[S], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def initial_state(self) -> S:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def delta(self, state: S, x: int) -> S:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_final(self, state: S) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Counter(Automata[int]):
    def initial_state(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def delta(self, state: int, x: int) -> int:
        return state + x

    def is_final(self, state: int) -> bool:
        return state >= 10


class Cont(Generic[R], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, automata: Automata[S]) -> R:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class EAutomata(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """
    ∃S. Automata[S]
    """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def unpack(self, cont: Cont[R]) -> R:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @staticmethod
    def pack(automata: Automata[S]) -> 'EAutomata':
        return EAutomataBody[S](automata)


class EAutomataBody(EAutomata, Generic[S]):
    def __init__(self, automata: Automata[S]):
        self._automata = automata

    def unpack(self, cont: Cont[R]) -> R:
        return cont(self._automata)


class Test:
    automata: EAutomata

    def __init__(self, automata: Automata[S]):
        self.automata = EAutomata.pack(automata)

    def test(self) -> bool:
        class C(Cont[bool]):
            def __call__(self, automata: Automata[S]) -> bool:
                s0 = automata.initial_state()
                # reveal_type(automata) #=> Automata[S`-1]
                # reveal_type(s0) #=> S`-1
                s1 = automata.delta(s0, 1)
                s2 = automata.delta(s1, 2)
                s3 = automata.delta(s2, 3)
                return automata.is_final(s3)
        return self.automata.unpack(C())


test = Test(Counter())
test.test()
```

Is there a way to simplify the above way, or is there a better way to use existential types in Python?

Comment: Can’t you make a generic `_Test` that does depend on `S` and contains the `test` function and then use the unspecialized `_Test` as an attribute of the exposed `Test`?